# how to install the cmake with specific version on WSL ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, cmake, clion

I am currently trying to link my CLion to WSL, but CLion only supported the Cmake of version 3.20.x, not the latest version, so I wonder how to downgrade my Cmake (version 3.21.3) to 3.20.x on Ubuntu

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question didn't say so, but the version (3.21.3) suggests that you are using the Snap package of cmake (not a deb package).

Here's the output of `snap info cmake`, edited for clarity:

```
[...]
channels:
  latest/stable:    3.21.3                 2021-09-21 (936) 116MB classic
  [...]                                            
  3.21/stable:      3.21.3                 2021-09-21 (936) 116MB classic
  [...]                                             
  3.20/stable:      3.20.6                 2021-09-21 (930) 115MB classic
  [...]
```

This tells us that you are likely using the `latest/stable` channel, which currently provides version 3.21.3. Version 3.20.6 is available on a different channel (the `3.20/stable` channel).

- At the moment, you cannot use multiple channels simultaneously: Installing B will remove A.

You should be able to install the 3.20.x version using:

```
sudo snap refresh cmake --channel=3.20/stable
```

And then you can return to latest using:

```
sudo snap refresh cmake --channel=latest/stable
```

Comment: it works!! thanks